# how to explain z score?

Tags: statistical-significance, data-mining, z-score

I am trying to understand the below result set. F20 variable binned into two groups 0 and 1-722. The question I am posing here is for bin 0. I have responders variable as population1 and non-responders variable as population2. I also have %proportion for responders and non responders. INDEX is in % too and is the proportion of responders/proportion non-responders. When I calculated the zscore I got -9.38. Index shows 99 which means ratio of the proportion for both population is very similar yet the zscore is so high. Can anyone explain me please. Forgive me for my little statistics knowledge.

- N1=population1
- N2=population2
- P1 = proportion1
- P2=proportion2

and the formula is as follows:

P = $\frac{(P1*N1)+(P2*N2)}{N1+N2}$; PP = $\frac{1}{N1}$+$\frac{1}{N2};

SE = $\sqrt{(P*(1-P)*PP)}$; ZSCORE = $\frac{P1-P2}{SE}$

[image]

Comment: Why do you start your question from "-2 down vote favorite"?! Is it a copy and paste from other question?! Moreover, your question is poorly worded and unclear, please edit to make it more clear what do you mean.

Comment: You are right Tim. I had it in stackoverflow and then realized stackoverflow is not the right place for this question so copied and pasted here. Oops!

Comment: Please explain how you compute a "zscore" and what you are hoping it tells you.

Comment: @poshan you could have flagged it for migration instead.

Comment: @whuber: Just added the formula. I am trying to see if one population is under or over represented by looking at the index variable. In this particular instance a got an index of 99. Then I calculated Zscore to see if two proportions are significantly different.A score of -9.38 tells me they do. I am not sure if this is true since the ratio of the two proportion is 99. Any explanation would be helpful.

Comment: You have a huge dataset.  It can detect a difference in proportions that is just one-fifth the size of the difference you have found.  Typically, statistical significance is of little concern when so much data are available: interest focuses on (a) whether the data are representative and (b) the sizes of any differences found.

Comment: @whuber: I appreciate your explanation. Could you explain " It can detect a difference in proportions that is just one-fifth the size of the difference you have found". Thank you